# Monaco Editor doesn't load codicons in case of using Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, monaco-editor

When trying using [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) in case of using Webpack, codicons are not loaded. I used the monaco-editor-webpack-plugin and followed the [instruction](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/webpack-plugin), but currently I can't any icons on the Monaco Editor instance in my test page.

[image]

Did I forget something to load the codicons?

You can reproduce this issue with: https://github.com/yoichiro/monaco-editor-test/tree/main

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .source-editor {
                width: 640px;
                height: 320px;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="source-editor"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        monaco.editor.create(document.querySelector('.source-editor'));
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const MonacoEditorWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', 'scss', 'html'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MonacoEditorWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' }),
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
  devServer: {
    static: './build',
    // open: true,
    watchFiles: ['src/**/*'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Webpack 5, we need to use [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead of loaders.

That is, the following code works on Webpack 5:

```
{
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  type: 'asset/resource'
}
```

If using Webpack 4 and lower, the following code will work:

```
{
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  use: ['file-loader']
}
```

Comment: I will send feedback about this to the Monaco Editor GitHub repository.

Comment: The instruction guide has already been updated. https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/webpack-plugin

Comment: First option for webpack 5 still does not work for me - same error.

Comment: Same here, assets don't work with WP 5.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as of Aug 2023. Following this [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2930) fixed the issue for me.

Namely, downgrading `css-loader` to `^5.2.7`.

I also followed the answer to this post, since i'm using webpack5.

```js
{
  test: /\.ttf$/,
  type: 'asset/resource'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mihai's answer was the solution for me. I have installed monaco in a mirrored web page, and just had to correct codicon as described by Mihai.

```
 [class^="codicon-"], [class*="codicon-"] {
        font-family: "codicon"!important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The css inserted by monaco for elements that have codicon font icons have by default `font-family: inherit;`.

```
.codicon-find-previous-match:before {
    content: '\eaa1';
}
```

Unless you have provided some custom icon font for codicon codes make sure you have a CSS rule that specifies the font-family provided by monaco-editor:

```
 [class^="codicon-"], [class*="codicon-"] {
        font-family: "codicon"!important;
 }
```